# Does the body make alterations to fatty acids before their storage?

Tags: biochemistry, fat-metabolism

I was wondering if you would be at all able to help me with some questions I can’t find the answers to. I’m a first-year uni student doing some research for the fun of it but I’m really struggling to answer some of the questions I’ve thought up and would greatly appreciate any help!

I’m trying to research how the body stores the fat it consumes. I understand that fat is stored in adipocytes as triacyl glycerides (TAGs) but I’m trying to find some information on which fats the body stores.
For example, if you were to consume some olive oil (oleic acid), would the body synthesise TAGs from the oleic acid or would the body convert the oleic acid into another fatty acid before this step (like palmitic acid)? Does this have any impact on the body’s ability to store fat (or the energy density of the fat?)? Does the body have a preferential approach to the storage of saturated vs unsaturated fats and are these fats stored in different places preferentially?

I’ve read through 9th Edition Biochemistry by Berg, J et al. (2019) which is where I raised these questions from. I’ve also looked through 3rd edition Molecular Biology and I’ve read a few papers on Google Scholar but none of them had the answers I was looking for.

If anyone would be able to offer any help, I would be eternally grateful Thank you in advance!

Mason

Comment: The books you have consulted may be good for certain things, but not for mammalian energy metabolism. Older books such as Lehninger are more suitable. Looking at the really old literature (1965) some fatty acids will be oxidized to acetyl CoA, whereas others would appear to be utilized directly. If this is your research project you need to start with this older work (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02636928.pdf) — use your university library to access it — and search for more sophisticated recent studies on Google Scholar using a query like "fate of dietary fatty acids".